# How can I parse the following string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, coordinates

I have a string value.

```
NSString *myString = @"Latitude:-31.9504140#Longitude:115.8606040";
```

How can I retrieve the latitude and longitude value from the string and assign it to coordinate

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.Latitude;
coordinate.Longitude;
```

Comment: your string formate is same every time..

Comment: Yes. Maybe slight change in values like 31.9504140

Comment: then use my answer it will help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if your format is same then you can get Latitude and Longitude using below code

```
NSString *myString = @"Latitude:-31.9504140#Longitude:115.8606040";
NSString *Latitude = [[[[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"] objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *Longitude = [[[[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"Latitude--%@,Longitude---%@",Latitude,Longitude);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
double lon, lat;
sscanf([myString UTF8String], "Latitude:%lf#Longitude:%lf", &lon, &lat);
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lon, lat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
NSArray *components = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSArray *latitude = [[components objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSArray *longitude = [[components objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.Latitude = [[latitude objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
coordinate.Longitude = [[longitude objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
```